# Trying to set up a .ka domain name

Tags: dns, domain-name

I'm trying to set up a domain with the .ka suffix for a URL shortener for a project I'm working on. Similar to drbl.in for example. I've checked online and this suffix doesn't seemed to registered to any country yet or appear of any domain name service. Any ideas on how to fix this up, or if its even possible?

Thanks

Comment: All 2 letter codes are reserved for countries. The only way to get it set up is to found a country that uses those letters, get the UN to recognize you as a country and then ask IANA to help you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no .ka TLD.  So you'll have to pick a different one.

Full TLD List: http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt

Answer (score 5):

Here is a list of [all top-level domains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains). Since .ka is not on that list, you cannot register a domain ending in .ka.

In terms of having that domain added, refer to the [IANA procedure for establishing new country-code TLDs](http://www.iana.org/procedures/cctld-establishment.html). The short version is: pick a new suffix.

Answer (score 1):

As the others have said, the .ka domain extension does not exist.

It's quite difficult to get a new domain extension approved. ICANN, which accepts applications for making new TLDs, opens this registration process only every few years and it is also quite expensive.

**Here's more info on getting your own TLD:** https://theaudacitytopodcast.com/afilias-explains-how-to-get-your-own-top-level-domain-tld/

If you're only after domain hacking and are not too particular about the spelling (as long as it sounds the same), then you might want to consider a .ca domain instead.

If you're interested, you can check if your domain hack is still available here:
https://www.marcaria.com/ws/en/domains/canada-domain-registration-ca